# wicket DropDownChoice jump to certain selection

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

I am using wicket [`DropDownChoice`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/DropDownChoice.html) and my list is very long, is there a way that when i click the drop down list and then click on a character the list will jump to the first select that start with the same character

Comment: Isn't this how normal `<select>` tag works? Wicket is irrelevant here, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/nurkiewicz/BzzrD/

Comment: no this does not work in wicket, select tag does work but in dropdownchoice this does not work

Comment: Interesting. Can you post HTML code generated by Wicket? Looking at JavaDoc it's pretty clean HTML... Maybe there is some extra JavaScript that intercepts key presses?

Comment: You must be doing something special here. Just tested it and it works as expeced in Wicket. Perhaps you use some javascript here? Can you show some code?

Comment: Which version of Wicket you're using? What you've described works for me under Wicket 1.4.20.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not the exact solution to your problem, but it will solve your functional issue. If you have very long select list, I would recommend loading it progressively with a search field via Ajax.

[wicket-select2](https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2) is such a (wonderful) wicket component, integrating the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) library into wicket to provide Ajax filtering, custom rendering, etc. Although the current integration doesn't offer a way to simply add the select2 behaviour to a static non ajax DropDownChoice, it's relatively easy to do by using wicket-select2's classes as a base. For the wicket-select2 integration all you'll need is to use `Select2Choice` (or `Select2MultiChoice` for multiple selects) to which you pass a simple `TextChoiceProvider`

After you start using such a component, you don't really want to go back to plain old selects, in particular if you have long lists of choices.

Note : using 1.5.8 (and previously 1.4.x), the old selects in my application display the behaviour you are looking for, e.g. standard html behaviour. However from what I understood you don't use a `<select>` tag in your markup for your DropDownChoice: what are you using then (it's likely this is the cause of your issue).